# removal of double cell protection google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a script that protects the cell after adding an entry. After deleting an entry, it disables protection.
Unfortunately, if someone overwrites in a sheet cell, it protects twice. When an entry is deleted, it removes only one protection. Is there any way to make it remove all protections?

```
function findProtectionFromRange(range) {
  let row = range.getRow();
  let col = range.getColumn();

  let protections = range.getSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  return protections.find((protection) => {
    let protectionRange = protection.getRange();
    if (row === protectionRange.getRow() && col === protectionRange.getColumn()) {
      return protection;
    }

    return null;
  });
}

function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let protection = findProtectionFromRange(range);
  
  if (e.value === undefined && protection) {
    protection.remove();
    return;
```

Answer (score 2):

All right, you have a script that protects a cell once the value is entered, right?

The solution is simple, then, check if the cell is already protected before protecting it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know much about programming. I found this code for sheet cell protection. Can you write what it should look like?

Comment: @siwy Check the documentation. Google is famous for documenting its API's to death. You'll be able to find how to check for a protected cell. Try doing it yourself first. It's far more satisfying, than having someone simply dump the code on you.